# Bootstrap3 datetimepicker shows calendar even when formatted?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, datetimepicker, timepicker

I have been using the bootstrap datetimepicker quite frequently in my project, but for some reason inside a bootstrap panel, the formatting does not work, and displays as a calendar. I have been trying to fix this for almost a day now, and am still really confused

My code is as follows....

```
  <div data-input="{{ key }}" class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title">{{key}}<a style="padding-left: 6px;">
      <span class="panel-time-picker"><input hidden type="text" value="" name="{{ key }}"><i class="icon-clock"></i></span></a></h3>
  <div class="actions pull-right">
      <a><i class="fa fa-trash delete-panel-btn"></i></a>
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" class="fa fa-chevron-down"></a>
  </div>
</div>



$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.panel-time-picker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'LT'
    });
    $('.panel-time-picker').datepicker();

});
```

I have the same exact JavaScript code elsewhere in my project, which turns the datepicker into a timepicker. I am wondering if this has something to do with being inside of a bootstrap accordion/panel?

This should display a time/clock, but still shows a month/day calendar? Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

[image]